# it is impossible to add winmd reference after update to VS2017 15.4.4

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, winmd

Desktop App Converter build no longer installs. 
I've been making desktop bridge apps over a year now.
All has been well up until recently updating visual studio to 15.4.4. I checked the references and winmd has the yellow dot of death on it.
Since updating to 15.4.4, no matter how many times i remove and manually browse to re-add, winmd just wont stick, and i get compile errors.

what do i do? is this a vs bug or is it me?

Comment: I manually referenced winmd in csproj with the full path, and have tried every darn configuration i can think of, using different .net frameworks, and using different target builds, no matter what i do, it just keeps throwing "cannot load file or assembly "Windows, Version 255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral...".  I've made over 100 build updates with no issues from late 2016 to now, but all of a sudden its hell from 15.4.4 =(

Comment: other projects dont have this problem. Just this one. Previous versions of this project don't have this problem. Why wont VS let me add the reference?

Comment: I've tried to see if it is workstation based. every workstation in my office (6) has the same result. All other desktop bridge solutions that im working on (4) have yet to have this same problem.

Comment: few weeks back, i submitted my app for permission to go to the store, but though it passed WACK, 10S still failed due to unsigned open source dlls, so my solution was to use Strong Namer. I just noticed that after buildling, the reference error shows up. Cleaning the solution also removes the reference error. My guess is the problem is with strong namer. :UPDATE: It's definitely strong namer. I uninstalled it, and we are back in business. Now i have to find another solution for signing the open source dlls

Answer (score 0):

I added Brutal Dev via nu Get to every project that requires auto strong naming.

Make sure to sign the assemblies first.
(right click on every project, under build, make a signature, then sign every project with that signature.

Then add Brutal Dev's Strong namer, then build.